# Are questions on graphical design of technical documents eligible?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I want to ask questions on graphical design details of technical documents. Would they be eligible on writers.SE or should I ask them elsewhere?

For example I need clarification about the naming of some graphical guidance methods like popup callouts, "zoom in"s etc, about their popularity or viability. I can't even be sure of their nomenclature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a spectrum.

At one end, we have questions already about layout -- things like separating chunks within a chapter, formatting poetry in running text, whether to show the screen shots before or after the corresponding documentation, and so on.  Clearly, then, the *presentation* of writing is on-topic.  Questions about using pop-up callouts or linking versus embedding referenced material or formatting for a phone are also on-topic.

At the other end are technical implementation questions.  A question about CSS or how to produce such-and-such effect in Photoshop<sup>1</sup> or what you should name your JavaScript classes internally would be off-topic.

There's a lot of space in between and we haven't had a lot of questions in this space, so if uncertain, I suggest trying.  Having actual *examples* to use to determine this part of our scope, rather than just hypothetical questions, should be a big help.  I'll apologize in advance if some of them get closed as off-topic, but we'll help you migrate those to other sites if possible so you still get answers.

<sup>1</sup> We do allow tools questions, though not the really basic ones like "how do I make things bold in Word?".  But questions that are purely about making graphics are not really writing questions, even if those graphics are being used in your writing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Thanks for bringing your question here, and I hope we're able to help you with the questions you want to ask on main.